# SQL how to compare two fields?

Tags: sql

Could I get a little help/direction on this? I am new to SQL and having a difficult time finding what direction to go in here. I have 2 fields I need to compare and supply an answer based on what is in those fields. So field 1 & 2 could have data = a,b,c or d. Based on the comparison the answer could be 0 through 4.

- IF a & a THEN 0
- IF a & b THEN 1
- IF a or b & c THEN 2
- IF c & c THEN 3
- IF a or b or c & d THEN 4

How would I best approach this in SQL?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using **case when** expression in your query

Comment: @Kikuta . . . You mention two fields.  But your pseudocode refers to four entities.  It is rather difficult to decipher your intention.

Comment: I apologize that my intent wasn't clear, my terminology may be off. So in each of the 2 "fields" could be the value of (a,b,c,d). They would then spit out an answer of (0,1,2,3,4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a `case` expression.  I think the logic you are trying to express is:

```
(case when field1 = 'a' and field2 = 'a' then 0
      when field1 = 'a' and field2 = 'b' then 1
      when field1 in ('a', 'b') and field2 = 'c' then 2
      when field1 = 'c' and field2 = 'c' then 3
      else 4
 end)
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a use case for a `CASE` expression. Your requirement litteraly translates as:

```
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN col1 = 'a'         AND col2 = 'a' THEN 0
    WHEN col1 = 'a'         AND col2 = 'b' THEN 1
    WHEN col1 IN ('a', 'b') AND col2 = 'c' THEN 2
    WHEN col1 = 'c'         AND col2 = 'c' THEN 3
    WHEN col1 IN ('a', 'b', 'c') AND col2 = 'd') THEN 4
END result
FROM ...
```

If none of the conditions is met (eg `col1 = 'd'` and `col2 = 'd'`), then the expression will return `NULL` (to define a proper value in this case, you can add a `ELSE` clause).